# Example of using "devoir" in passé composé?

Tags: usage, passé-composé

Can any one offer a relatively simple example sentence that uses devoir in the passé composé? I'm having trouble figuring out when it would be used.

Comment: In which way _devoir_ is special that its use in _passé composé_ would be problematic?

Comment: Apparently none =), but I was having trouble seeing that. See my comment below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ce matin, j'avais oublié mon sac à la maison. **J'ai dû** retourner le chercher.

> **Ils** se sont très mal comportés et **ont dû** aller présenter leurs excuses.

Comment: Simple enough, thanks! I think I was having trouble figuring out when it would be in p.c. and when it would be imperfect. That, and google translate kept using "avoir besoin".